# Use Puppeteer in class methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, puppeteer

i am asking if it is possible i could use Puppeteer in class methods. I read a lot about async/await functions but i could not find anything regarding classes. I currently have this:

```
class Tools{
  async login() {
    this.browser = ppt.launch({
      headless: true,
    });
    this.page = this.browser.newPage();
    this.page.type('#email','test');
   ...
  }
```

Main method:

```
(async function main() {
  try {

    const tools = await new Tools();
  } catch(e) {
    console.log('Error: ' + e);
  }
})();
```

Any advice on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are just calling the constructor in your code. You also need to call the `login` function. Also you don't want to put the `await` in front of your constructor but in front of `login`.

**Code**

```js
const tools = new Tools();
await tools.login();
```

#### About `async` constructor functions

Be aware that you cannot use constructor calls (`new Tools`) with `await`. The reason is, that `await` waits for the returned Promise to be resolved. But constructor functions cannot return a Promise as they need to return the newly created object.

That's why libraries like puppeteer use factory functions like `puppeteer.launch`. These functions will create an object in addition to calling asynchronous functions afterwards. If you want to do something similar in your code, you can do it like this:

```js
class Tools {
  async initialize() {
    // ...
  }
  static async create() {
    const newObject = new Tools();
    await newObject.initialize();
  }
}


const tools = await Tools.create();
```

Comment: But you cannot use await with class constructor?

Comment: @KyleKluge No, that's why libraries like puppeteer use factory functions like `launch` instead. I will add it to the answer.

Comment: Can we use async methods inside constructor? Like this: `constructor() { await create(); }`?

Comment: @MatejJ No, this is not possible. The constructor has to be synchronous. In my sample code above, you would put that code in the `initialize` function instead.

Answer (score 1):

> headless: true

Make puppeteer to run in Headless mode, meaning it will execute your code, but you'll not have any chrome openning

if you want to see what's hapenning in real time for debugging purposes, initialize puppeteer without the headleass mode

```
this.browser = ppt.launch({
  headless: false,
});
```

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake. FIxed it, but still i want to write my methods in class